# When publishing an Animate CC .fla file, the .js will not play

Tags: javascript, animate-cc

I am new to animation, so my apologies if my vocabulary does not make complete sense.

When I go to play my .js file, only this code comes up in both chrome and safari :

```
 (function (cjs, an) {

    var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
    var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
    lib.webFontTxtInst = {}; 
    var loadedTypekitCount = 0;
    var loadedGoogleCount = 0;
    var gFontsUpdateCacheList = [];
    var tFontsUpdateCacheList = [];
    lib.ssMetadata = [];



    lib.updateListCache = function (cacheList) {        
    for(var i = 0; i < cacheList.length; i++) {     
        if(cacheList[i].cacheCanvas)        
            cacheList[i].updateCache();     
        }       
    };      

    lib.addElementsToCache = function (textInst, cacheList) {       
    var cur = textInst;     
    while(cur != null && cur != exportRoot) {       
        if(cacheList.indexOf(cur) != -1)        
            break;      
        cur = cur.parent;       
        }       
        if(cur != exportRoot) {     
        var cur2 = textInst;        
        var index = cacheList.indexOf(cur);     
        while(cur2 != null && cur2 != cur) {        
            cacheList.splice(index, 0, cur2);       
            cur2 = cur2.parent;     
            index++;        
        }       
        }       
      else {        
        cur = textInst;     
        while(cur != null && cur != exportRoot) {       
            cacheList.push(cur);        
            cur = cur.parent;       
        }       
      }     
      };        

    lib.gfontAvailable = function(family, totalGoogleCount) {       
    lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;     
    var txtInst = lib.webFontTxtInst && lib.webFontTxtInst[family] || [];       
    for(var f = 0; f < txtInst.length; ++f)     
        lib.addElementsToCache(txtInst[f], gFontsUpdateCacheList);      

    loadedGoogleCount++;        
    if(loadedGoogleCount == totalGoogleCount) {     
        lib.updateListCache(gFontsUpdateCacheList);     
    }       
    };      

    lib.tfontAvailable = function(family, totalTypekitCount) {      
    lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;     
    var txtInst = lib.webFontTxtInst && lib.webFontTxtInst[family] || [];       
    for(var f = 0; f < txtInst.length; ++f)     
        lib.addElementsToCache(txtInst[f], tFontsUpdateCacheList);      

    loadedTypekitCount++;       
    if(loadedTypekitCount == totalTypekitCount) {       
        lib.updateListCache(tFontsUpdateCacheList);     
    }       
    };
    // symbols:
    // helper functions:

    function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode,
          this.startPosition, this.loop));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
    }

    function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }


    (lib.touch = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();

               this.shape.graphics.f("#969696").s().p("AjjDkQheheAAiGQAAiFBeheQBfheCEAAQCFAABfBeQBeBeAACFQAACGheBeQhfBeiFAAQiEAAhfheg");
    this.shape.setTransform(32.3,32.2);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.touch, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,64.5,64.5), null);


(lib.startvinetwo = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#4AB54F").s().p("AG0QjQGdpXBbs+QBApShmqLQghjLgti5IgmiQQFZRbhEOHQg2LRk6IsQjhGNlMERQimCJh5A5IucCIQPhlUIErtg");
    this.shape.setTransform(107.4,214.8);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.startvinetwo, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,214.9,429.6), null);


(lib.startvineone = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#4AB54F").s().p("AtIF0QhKrQDTpaQCXmvEXlHQCLikBthOIN2kpQuVH+l5M8QktKWA6NCQApJUDYJuQBbEJBWCyQn8vphatrg");
    this.shape.setTransform(86,224.8);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.startvineone, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,172.1,449.7), null);


(lib.planttownheader = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AA/CXQgXgBAAgPQAAgHAIgBQAJABADgEQAFgGAAgTIAAiDQAAgmgHgQQgKgZgfAAQgjAAgYAhQgWAhAAAsIAABkQAAATAFAGQADAEAJgBQAIABAAAHQAAAPgWABIg3AAQgWgBAAgPQAAgHAIgBQAIABADgEQAGgGAAgTIAAi7QAAgTgFgGQgEgEgIgBQgIABAAgJQAAgHAIgEQAGgDAIAAIAnAAQAJAAADAHQACAFAAAQIgBAgQASgfAegTQAbgUAcAAQAqAAARAWQARAUAAAyIAACdQAAATAFAGQADAEAIgBQAIABAAAHQAAAPgWABg");
    this.shape.setTransform(146.2,97.4);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("ABMCMQgGgIgIgXIg9iyIhFC5QgHATgHAHQgHAHgLAAQgOAAgHgkIgqjDQgGgbgGgIQgFgIgMAAQgHAAAAgIQAAgPAWAAIA6AAQAWAAAAAPQAAAIgIAAQgLAAAAAQQAAAGAFAdIAeCXIBLjHQAGgRAEgFQADgEAHAAQAJAAAEAGQADAFAGATIBCDDIAjisQADgIAAgIQAAgOgLAAQgIAAAAgIQAAgPAWAAIAmAAQATAAAAAPQAAAIgJAAQgHAAgFAFQgGAHgEARIgzDUQgEARgGAIQgGAIgJAAQgKAAgHgJg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(109.5,98.1);

    this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_2.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AhjBwQgkgqAAhHQAAhKApgpQAmgmA4AAQBBAAAjApQAkAoAABJQAABHgqArQgmApg3AAQg/gBglgqgAhRgKQgBA+AWAmQAXAmAmABQAngBAWgeQAUgfABg6QgBhAgVglQgXgkgmAAQhRAAAAB2g");
    this.shape_2.setTransform(73.5,97.8);

    this.shape_3 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_3.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AgfDXQgXAAAAgMQAAgEABgCQACgBAFAAQATAAAAggIAAldIgkAAQgtAAgNAbIgJAdQgFASgJAAQgNAAAAhEQAAgSACgHQADgKAMAAIAiACIDVAAIAhgCQAMAAAEAKQACAHAAASQAABEgNAAQgJAAgFgSIgJgdQgNgbgtAAIgkAAIAAFdQAAAgATAAQAIAAAAAHQAAAMgXAAg");
    this.shape_3.setTransform(43.5,90.9);

    this.shape_4 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_4.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AgUC3QgUgRAAgvIAAi8IgcAAQgNAAAAgKQAAgJAQgJQAVgLAIgMQAIgMADgbQADgWACgDQADgLAKABQAJAAADACQAEAEAAAMIAABOIA/AAQAKAAAAAJQAAAKgHAFQgGAFgIAAIg0AAIAACtQAAAlAKANQAMAOAlAAQAGAAACABQADADAAAHQAAAJgUAEQgOADgTAAQggAAgOgMg");
    this.shape_4.setTransform(118.4,24);

    this.shape_5 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_5.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AA+CXQgWAAAAgPQAAgIAIAAQAIAAADgEQAGgGAAgTIAAiDQAAgmgHgQQgKgZgfAAQgjAAgYAiQgWAfAAAtIAABkQAAATAFAGQADAEAIAAQAJAAAAAIQAAAPgWAAIg3AAQgWAAAAgPQAAgIAIAAQAIAAADgEQAFgGAAgTIAAi7QAAgTgEgGQgEgEgIAAQgIAAAAgJQAAgOAWAAIAnAAQAIAAADAHQADAGAAAPIgBAgQASgfAdgUQAcgTAbAAQAqAAASAWQARAUAAAyIAACdQAAATAFAGQADAEAIAAQAIAAAAAIQAAAPgWAAg");
    this.shape_5.setTransform(92.2,28.3);

    this.shape_6 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_6.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AhiCIQgVgTAAgnQAAgtAhgWQAVgMBDgRQAugMAAgTIAAgsQAAgMgKgKQgMgMgXAAQgnAAgTAoIgKAVQgHAMgIAAQgJAAgEgRQgCgLAAgOQAAgeAPgJQAIgEAYgGQAegHAdAAQBXAAAAA+IAAC4QAAARADAHQADAHAIAAQAIAAAAAIQAAAIgJAFQgJAEgMAAQgWAAgIgFQgMgJAAgZIAAgNQgnA3g8AAQgdAAgSgRgAAEAEQgnALgNALQgUAPAAAfQAAASAHAMQAKARAXAAQAbAAAUgSQATgQAKgXIAAhLQgLAJghAIg");
    this.shape_6.setTransform(61.7,28.8);

    this.shape_7 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_7.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AgZDZQgYAAAAgPQAAgIAIAAQAJAAACgDQAGgHAAgTIAAlKQAAgRgFgGQgCgFgKAAQgIAAAAgJQAAgOAYAAIAkAAQAJAAADAKQACAGAAANIAAFgQAAATAFAHQAEADAHAAQAIAAAAAIQAAAPgWAAg");
    this.shape_7.setTransform(40,21.7);

    this.shape_8 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_8.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AiCDWQgYAAAAgMQAAgIAIABQATgBAAgfIAAlFQAAgggTAAQgIABAAgIQAAgMAXAAICSAAQA3AAAlAWQAwAcAAA+QAABLg3AkQgnAbg0AAQg5AAgXgKIAACIQAAAfASABQAJgBAAAIQAAAMgYAAgAg7i2QgMAEAAATIAACGQAAAiBDAAQAsAAAagTQAegZAAg2QAAhhhoAAQgpAAgKAEg");
    this.shape_8.setTransform(15.5,22);

    this.shape_9 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_9.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AgxBgQgOAAAAgLQAAgEAFAAQAFgBACgCQAEgEAAgMIAAh4QAAgKgCgEQgDgFgFAAQgGAAAAgEQAAgKAPAAIAYAAQAJAAAAAOIAAAVQAJgSAPgLQAPgJAPgBQAZAAAAASQAAALgEAHQgEAGgGAAQgEAAgHgJQgIgIgJAAQgSAAgKATQgJASAAAYIAABHQAAAMADAEQACACAGABQAEAAAAAEQAAALgNAAg");
    this.shape_9.setTransform(119.2,363.6);

    this.shape_10 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_10.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("Ag3BLQgXgaAAguQAAgwAWgbQAWgbAlAAQAkAAAVAXQATAVAAAiQAAAVgOAAIhsAAQAAAgALAVQAPAZAcAAQASAAAMgHQAKgGAJgNQAEgGAFgBQAIAAAAAIQAAADgCAFQgJASgTAKQgTAKgYAAQgkABgXgZgAgig7QgJAPAAAUQAAAFACACQABAAAEAAIBDAAQAIAAADgCQACgDAAgJQAAgUgJgNQgLgRgWAAQgYgBgMAXg");
    this.shape_10.setTransform(102,363.7);

    this.shape_11 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_11.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AgNB2QgNgLAAgfIAAh4IgRAAQgJAAAAgHQABgGAJgFQAOgHAFgHQAFgJACgRIAEgQQABgHAHAAQAFAAACACQACACABAIIAAAyIAoAAQAHAAgBAGQAAAGgEAEQgDADgFAAIgiAAIAABvQgBAYAIAIQAHAJAYAAQADAAACABQACABAAAFQAAALgjAAQgUAAgJgIg");
    this.shape_11.setTransform(86.4,360.6);

    this.shape_12 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_12.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("AAoBhQgOAAAAgKQAAgFAFAAQAFAAACgDQAEgDAAgNIAAhTQAAgYgEgLQgHgQgUAAQgWAAgPAWQgPAUAAAcIAABAQAAANADADQACADAGAAQAFAAAAAFQAAAKgOAAIgjAAQgOAAAAgKQAAgFAFAAQAFAAACgDQADgDAAgNIAAh3QAAgMgDgEQgCgDgFAAQgFAAAAgGQAAgIAOgBIAZAAQAFABACAEQACADAAAKIgBAVQAMgUATgNQARgMASAAQAbAAALAOQALANAAAgIAABkQAAANADADQACADAFAAQAFAAAAAFQAAAKgOAAg");
    this.shape_12.setTransform(69.5,363.4);

    this.shape_13 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_13.graphics.f("#231F20").s().p("Ag3BLQgXgaAAguQAAgwAWgbQAWgbAlAAQAkAAAUAXQAUAVAAAiQAAAVgOAAIhsAAQgBAgAMAVQAOAZAdAAQASAAALgHQALgGAJgNQADgGAGgBQAHAAABAIQgBADgBAFQgJASgTAKQgTAKgYAAQgkABgXgZgAgig7QgJAPAAAUQAAAFACACQABAAAEAAIBDAAQAIAAACgCQACgDAAgJQABgUgJgNQgLgRgWAAQgZgBgLAXg");
    this.shape_13.setTransform(49.8,363.7);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_13},{t:this.shape_12},{t:this.shape_11},{t:this.shape_10},{t:this.shape_9},{t:this.shape_8},{t:this.shape_7},{t:this.shape_6},{t:this.shape_5},{t:this.shape_4},{t:this.shape_3},{t:this.shape_2},{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.planttownheader, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,160.2,373.6), null);


// stage content:
(lib.planttown = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // planttownheader
    this.instance = new lib.planttownheader();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(177.7,497.1,1,1,0,0,0,80,186.8);
    this.instance.alpha = 0;
    this.instance._off = true;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(5).to({_off:false},0).wait(1).to({regX:80.1,x:177.8,alpha:0.04},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.08},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.12},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.16},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.2},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.24},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.28},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.32},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.36},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.4},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.44},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.48},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.52},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.56},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.6},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.64},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.68},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.72},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.76},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.8},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.84},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.88},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.92},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.96},0).wait(1).to({alpha:1},0).wait(22));

    // startvineone
    this.instance_1 = new lib.startvineone();
    this.instance_1.parent = this;
    this.instance_1.setTransform(135,-65,1,1,0,0,0,86,224.8);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_1).wait(1).to({y:-58.2},0).wait(1).to({y:-51.4},0).wait(1).to({y:-44.6},0).wait(1).to({y:-37.8},0).wait(1).to({y:-31},0).wait(1).to({y:-24.3},0).wait(1).to({y:-17.5},0).wait(1).to({y:-10.7},0).wait(1).to({y:-3.9},0).wait(1).to({y:2.9},0).wait(1).to({y:9.7},0).wait(1).to({y:16.5},0).wait(1).to({y:23.3},0).wait(1).to({y:30.1},0).wait(1).to({y:36.9},0).wait(1).to({y:43.7},0).wait(1).to({y:50.5},0).wait(1).to({y:57.3},0).wait(1).to({y:64},0).wait(1).to({y:70.8},0).wait(1).to({y:77.6},0).wait(1).to({y:84.4},0).wait(1).to({y:91.2},0).wait(1).to({y:98},0).wait(1).to({y:104.8},0).wait(1).to({y:111.6},0).wait(1).to({y:118.4},0).wait(1).to({y:125.2},0).wait(1).to({y:132},0).wait(1).to({y:138.8},0).wait(1).to({y:145.5},0).wait(1).to({y:152.3},0).wait(1).to({y:159.1},0).wait(1).to({y:165.9},0).wait(1).to({y:172.7},0).wait(1).to({y:179.5},0).wait(1).to({y:186.3},0).wait(1).to({y:193.1},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.923},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.846},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.769},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.692},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.615},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.538},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.462},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.385},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.308},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.231},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.154},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.077},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0},0).wait(1));

    // startvinetwo
    this.instance_2 = new lib.startvinetwo();
    this.instance_2.parent = this;
    this.instance_2.setTransform(207.1,865.3,1,1,0,0,0,107.4,214.8);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_2).wait(1).to({y:858.7},0).wait(1).to({y:852.1},0).wait(1).to({y:845.5},0).wait(1).to({y:838.9},0).wait(1).to({y:832.3},0).wait(1).to({y:825.8},0).wait(1).to({y:819.2},0).wait(1).to({y:812.6},0).wait(1).to({y:806},0).wait(1).to({y:799.4},0).wait(1).to({y:792.9},0).wait(1).to({y:786.3},0).wait(1).to({y:779.7},0).wait(1).to({y:773.1},0).wait(1).to({y:766.5},0).wait(1).to({y:760},0).wait(1).to({y:753.4},0).wait(1).to({y:746.8},0).wait(1).to({y:740.2},0).wait(1).to({y:733.6},0).wait(1).to({y:727.1},0).wait(1).to({y:720.5},0).wait(1).to({y:713.9},0).wait(1).to({y:707.3},0).wait(1).to({y:700.7},0).wait(1).to({y:694.2},0).wait(1).to({y:687.6},0).wait(1).to({y:681},0).wait(1).to({y:674.4},0).wait(1).to({y:667.8},0).wait(1).to({y:661.3},0).wait(1).to({y:654.7},0).wait(1).to({y:648.1},0).wait(1).to({y:641.5},0).wait(1).to({y:634.9},0).wait(1).to({y:628.4},0).wait(1).to({y:621.8},0).wait(1).to({y:615.2},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.923},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.846},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.769},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.692},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.615},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.538},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.462},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.385},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.308},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.231},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.154},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0.077},0).wait(1).to({alpha:0},0).wait(1));

    // touch1
    this.instance_3 = new lib.touch();
    this.instance_3.parent = this;
    this.instance_3.setTransform(177.1,663.1,1,1,0,0,0,32.2,32.2);
    this.instance_3._off = true;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_3).wait(30).to({_off:false},0).wait(1).to({scaleX:0.75,scaleY:0.75},0).wait(1).to({scaleX:0.5,scaleY:0.5,x:177},0).wait(2).to({scaleX:0.63,scaleY:0.63},0).wait(1).to({scaleX:0.75,scaleY:0.75,x:177.1},0).wait(1).to({scaleX:0.87,scaleY:0.87},0).wait(1).to({scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:177},0).wait(1).to({scaleX:1.12,scaleY:1.12,x:177.1},0).to({_off:true},1).wait(13));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(227.5,116.1,265.5,1369.9);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '03ADE9235BF949BC9D3CBC11DE5934B7',
    width: 357,
    height: 812,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    opacity: 1.00,
    webfonts: {},
    manifest: [],
    preloads: []
};



// bootstrap callback support:

(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
    createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();

p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
    this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
    an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}

an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
    an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
    if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
            fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
        }
    }
};

an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['03ADE9235BF949BC9D3CBC11DE5934B7'] = {
    getStage: function() { return exportRoot.getStage(); },
    getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
    getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
    getImages: function() { return img; }
};

an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
    an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
    for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
        an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
    }
}

an.getComposition = function(id) {
    return an.compositions[id];
}



})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
```

I have my publish settings all checked, the stage centered and it set to be reactive. I am not sure why it will not publish.

Thank You!

Comment: What are you asking? Are you running the generated html file? Running the JS will not do anything, as it is essentially a library of assets and animations